# How do I list results in my template with fatfree framework and cortex model?

Tags: templates, fat-free-framework

I am using fatfree framework with the Cortex ORM plugin, and I am trying to simply query the db and display the resulting rows within my template, so I tried:

In my controller:

```
$users = new \models\User;
$users->load();
$f3->set('users',$users);
/*while(!$users->dry()){
    echo '<br/>'.$users->id;
    $users->next();
}*/
echo \Template::instance()->render('pages/User/list.htm','text/html');
```

And in my template:

```
<repeat group="{{@users}}" value="{{@v}}">
    <div>{{@v.id}}</div>
</repeat>
```

But the template stays blank. In the controller however, if I uncomment the `while` block, then I do get the expected results, but how do I get it in my template?

Also if I remove the quotes and try `group={{@users}}`, I get `instance of class cannot be converted to string` error. So how do I loop through the results from within my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$users->load()` maps to *one* db row at a time.

What you need is an array containing the mappers for every row, so use `$users->find()` instead:

```
$users = new \models\User;
$f3->set('users',$users->find());
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! but even if load sets one record as active, shouldn't that single record be shown in the frontend?

Comment: Yes it would work if you removed the `<repeat>` tag. In your example, the `<repeat>` tag was looping through the mapper properties. Let's say your mapper did contain [id=3,name=Dude,age=27], then your template did loop through [3,Dude,27].